# Recuperar última linha inserida em tabela com chave primária não sequencial - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select

É possível saber qual foi a última linha inserida em uma tabela MySql em que a chave primária não é sequencial?

Tenho uma tabela onde a chave primária é composta por duas colunas que são FK, portanto elas não seguem uma sequência.

Quando executada a query `select last_insert_id();` é retornado 0 (Faz sentido, por que nenhum ID foi inserido mesmo).

A melhor saída é colocar uma coluna ID mesmo?

Comment: Posso estar enganado mas acho que o ID parece ser mais adequado.

Comment: Se este ID não vai impactar no uso da sua PK, é a melhor idéia. Uma outra possibilidade seria incluir um campo do tipo DateTime com DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (para obter o último é só fazer o ordenamento descendente) mas esta não é a melhor solução, principalmente do ponto de vista de performance da consulta.

Comment: É, acredito que uma coluna com auto-incremento é a melhor solução msm pensando em facilidade pra resolver o problema e desempenho. Obrigado!

Comment: Se é pra evitar o ID, pior ainda por data automática. Só sai mais "caro", e depende do relógio da máquina, e não suporta concorrência. ID não tem esses problemas, e é só ver o maior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione uma coluna com a data de inserção:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD insercao DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Ou um id de auto incremento:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: É, fiquei com a segunda opção mesmo, acredito ser a melhor pelo desempenho. Obrigado!